# Pivot table from multiple spreadsheets

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am using excel 2010.  I am trying to create pivot table between two worksheets 'Summary' and 'Summary2'. I have identical row of data ranging from cells B5 to F5 in row 5 in both worksheets. Data in the two worksheets looks like this:

Summary worksheet: Issues,20,3,4,5
Summary2 worksheet: Issues,10,0,3,9

Worksheet referes to issues from location 1 and worksheet referes to issues from location 2. Col B has title 'issues', Col C refers to issues of customer 1, Col D refers to issues of  customer 2, Col E refers to issues of  customer 3, Col F refers to issues of customer 4

I go to a third worksheet and start pivot table and in the table range I give this: 'Summary:Summary2'!$B$5:$F$5. Then I Say OK. Gives error "data reference source is not valid". Can someone tell me how to select the row from two different worksheet in pivot table?

Also I want to be able to add issues of customers between two locations and get % completion for each locaiton.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to consolidate two spread sheets.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/consolidate-data-in-multiple-worksheets-HP010095249.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-pivottable-report-HA010226585.aspx) is what you're looking for. Enabling the pivot table wizard will guide you through the steps. This is for 2007, but I assume the same wizard is in 2010.

Comment: Also is there a way I can have one pivot table that tracks planned work. Another pivot table that tracks actual completed work. Then can I compare the planned work with actual work, using the two pivot tables.

Comment: I can confirm that the wizard is still the only way to do this in Excel 2010. Also note that if you're referencing a table, reference it as `Table[#All]` to include the headers, otherwise things break badly.